# Post processing operations on pseudo-random generators

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

I am struggling to solve this proof.

The goal is to prove that $H \circ G$, which is a composite function $H(G(s))$ can be a pseudo-random generator under some conditions on $H$, given that $G$ is also a pseudo-random generator. Note that $H$ is length-preserving.

However, I can't find a way to prove (using the definition of a pseudo-random generator) that if $H$ is bijective, deterministic, can be computed in polynomial time and doesn't convey any information regarding the original input $s$, $H \circ G$ is also a pseudo-random generator.

I would appreciate some help on this topic.

Comment: Assume this isn't the case --- i.e. $H\circ G$ is *not* a PRG under your assumptions. What does this imply about $G$?

Comment: @Mark I guess that would mean that G cannot be a PRG. However, I can't find a way to prove this contradiction with the formal definition of a PRG

Comment: What does it mean for something to not be a PRG?

Comment: @Mark Informally speaking, if $G$ is not a PRG, then it would be possible for an adversary to distinguish between its output and a truly random string.

Comment: Exactly! So assume $H\circ G$ is not a PRG, i.e. there is an adversary $\mathcal{A}_{H\circ G}$ that distinguishes its output. Can you use this to create an adversary $\mathcal{A}_G$ against $G$?

Comment: I think that if $H$ is deterministic, then it would be possible for A to win over $G$

Comment: If you think so, try to prove it. Roughly, (formally) build $\mathcal{A}_G$ however you can, then see if the assumptions you require on $H$ are implied by the conditions you were given as part of the problem statement.